# Error:Newer :Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException

Tags: android, import, build.gradle

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/volume1/Android Studio/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

gradle:

```
     apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ibussinesscard"
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'


   // compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'

}
```

-- I have tried all possible solution available on stack-overflow and on Google..

-- I have issue in resolving imports..

--**Rebuild or clean or changing buildToolVersion is not working for me**

-- **Restarting or build-->Make project is also not working for me**

--  **multiDexEnabled true is also not working**

[image]

Comment: `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'`

Comment: i have already added multiDexEnable.. not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

1. **multiDexEnabled true**
2. call `v7:23.1.0`

Try with this

```
 android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ibussinesscard"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'

}
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Sync`** Your Project .

Comment: what about `buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"`

Comment: @tiger Feedback please

Comment: @tiger Update SDK Manager

Comment: What should i update in SDK manager ? check my edited question. i have upload image

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should try to change:
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
to  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.2'
It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;
import com.icrea.findmymacros.fragment.FMMHome_Fragment;
import com.icrea.findmymacros.fragment.MealDetailsWithExistUser_Fragment;
import com.icrea.findmymacros.fragment.MyProfile_Fragment;
import com.icrea.findmymacros.fragment.AddMeal_Fragment;
import com.icrea.findmymacros.app.AppController;
import com.icrea.findmymacros.fragment.PastMealSubmission_Fragment;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Home_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }


}
```

extend your main activity with Appcompact

Answer (score 0):

As you are running linux the issue might because **Permissions** try to provide Read-write permission to your **aapt**. Try below steps.

> 1. Open Terminal
> 2. chmod +777 "/volume1/Android Studio/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt"
> 3. Enter.

Try to rebuild the project now.